# How is Visual Studio 2008 Windows Forms Designer both QVGA and VGA Compatible?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-forms-designer, vga

In Visual Studio 2008 when working with a Smart Device project, if I use the Window Forms Designer to add controls to a form, then the controls will be displayed in the correct place when the program is actually running whether the device has a QVGA or VGA screen. However if I add controls to the form in my code manually without using the Designer, then I need have my code check at run time whether the device has a VGA screen or a QVGA screen. If it is a VGA screen I have to multiple the x, y, width, and height by 2 for each control added manually. Why is that only necessary for controls added without using the designer?

I just added a comment below the first answer.

Answer (score 1):

Controls that are added at design time are autoscaled when first drawn, due to these properties in the designer.cs:

```
this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(96F, 96F);
this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Dpi;
```

When you dynamically add controls at runtime you'll need to perform your own scaling. Its not ideal, but its just the way it works.

Comment: I still don't understand. The controls added by the designer are also dynamically added at runtime, it is just generated code. This is especially confusing when you have both designer added controls and controls added manually because the code you posted here would still exist.